# Aceitar entrada com apenas 1 dígito

Tags: python

Gostaria de saber uma maneira para aceitar apenas a entrada com 1 dígito. No caso abaixo: 1, 2 ou 3.

Entradas do tipo 0001, 01, 0002.. (com zero à esqueda) não fosse válido (apresentasse um erro) e retornasse para digitar novamente um número entre 1 e 3.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
def choice_game_to_play():
    playing = False
      
    
    try_login = 0
    
      print("*****************************************")
      print("*************CHOICE A GAME!**************")
      print("*****************************************\n")
    
      while not playing:
    
        try:      
          try_login += 1
    
          playing = try_login == 6
    
          print("(1) Roll dice - (2) Guess a number - (3) Jokenpo\n")
    
          game = int(input("Choice a game between 1 and 3: "))
         
          if game <= 0 or game > 3:
            print("\n**********Invalid value, try again!**********\n")
          else: 
            if game == 1:
              play_dice()  
            elif game == 2:
              play_guessing() 
            elif game == 3:
              play_jokenpo()
              
        except ValueError:
          print("\n*************Invalid value, try again!*************\n")
          continue
```

Comment: Tente: `game = input("Choice a game between 1 and 3: ")
while (game not in ["1", "2", "3"]):
     print("\n**********Invalid value, try again!**********\n")
     game = input("Choice a game between 1 and 3: ")
game = int(game)
`.

Comment: Hummm, entendi a lógica! Vou implementar. Valeu

Comment: Eu queria entender por que esta pergunta teve votos negativos.  Alguém dos que deu votos negativos poderia falar sobre?

Comment: Isso tem acontecido muito. As perguntas estão claras, bem estruturadas. Porém, parece que se a pessoa não entende, ou não sabe responder, vota negativo.

Answer (score 1):

A linha `game = int(input("Choice a game between 1 and 3: "))`  chama `int` e isso converte imediatamente o valor digitado para um inteiro (e se não for um inteiro, acontece um TypeError e o programa pula para o Except) - mas então, depois dessa conversão, se o usuário digitou "001", já fica na variável "game" apenas o valor numérico "1", e você não tem mais controle disso.

O melhor é aceitar o retorno do `input` como ele vem - que é uma string, e aí usar alguns `if`s para controlar o que for digitado, antes de extrair o valor inteiro dos números.

Isso tem a vantagem, além do `try...except` genérico no bloco todo que permite que mensagens mais apropriadas possam ser dados ao usuário a cada tentativa.

O código acima já faz uma parte disso com `if game <= 0 or game > 3:` - dá para fazer algo do tipo:

```py
while True:
   game_str = input("Choose a game between 1 and 3: ")
   if not game_str.isdigit():
       print("Please, pick a numeric choice")
       continue  # volta ao "while", repetindo a pergunta
   if len(game_str) != 1:  # Aqui trato o conteúdo como string: o valor digitado deve ter apena sum caractere
       print("Please, type just the number 1-3")
       continue
   game = int(game_str)  # só aqui converto o valor para numérico
   if 0 < game <=3:
       break # Valor entre 1 e 3 - saimos do "while True" que repete a pergunta sempre
   print("Please, the option should be in the range 1-3")

# codigo fora do While continua o jogo
...
```

Acima, além de pegar o conteúdo inicial como string, coloquei um "while True" que inclui a pergunta - e somente o teste no "if" que verifica se está tudo ok contém o comando "break" que faz o código sair do "while" e continuar. Enquanto não estiver tudo ok, por um motivo ou por outro, o while fica em execução e repete o `input`.

Answer (score 1):

Quando queremos restringir a quantidade de algarismos do número para apenas `"1"` algarismo, percebemos que desejamos números que apenas pertencem ao conjunto `[-9, 9]`, isto é...

```
numeros = [-9, -8, -7, -6 , -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Agora, como você está utilizando apenas os números `"1", "2" e "3"`, você pode converte-los em `"string"` e, em seguida, utiliza-los.

Outra coisa, quando trabalhamos com funções devemos saber como estrutura-las e como chama-las.

De acordo com o que você deseja, desenvolvi o seguinte código...

```
print("*************************************************")
print("*****************\033[34mCHOICE A GAME!\033[m******************")
print("*************************************************")
print()

def playDice():
    print('\nStarting Dice...')
    # Insert the game code "Dice" here!
    # Insira o código do jogo "Dice" aqui!


def playGuess():
    print('\nStarting Guess...')
    # Insert the game code "Guess" here!
    # Insira o código do jogo "Guess" aqui!


def playJokenpo():
    print('\nStarting Jokenpo...')
    # Insert the game code "Jokenpo" here!
    # Insira o código do jogo "Jokenpo" aqui!


def choice_game_to_play():

    print("(1) Roll dice - (2) Guess a number - (3) Jokenpo")

    game = input("Choice a game between 1 and 3: ").strip()
    while game not in '123':
        print("\n************\033[31mInvalid value, try again!\033[m************")
        game = str(input("Choice a game between 1 and 3: "))

    if game == '1':
        playDice()
    elif game == '2':
        playGuess()
    elif game == '3':
        playJokenpo()


choice_game_to_play()
```

Veja o funcionamento do código no [repl.it](https://repl.it/join/kgdyuglw-solkarped)